# Remove MyCompany.Task from the list of namespaces that .NET looks through

Tags: c#, .net-core, namespaces, nuget

I have a project imports a Nuget package with the namespace `MyCompany.Task`. My project file has a namespace of `MyCompany.MyProjectName.Services`.

I also have methods which have a return type of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` which is imported as `using System.Threading.Tasks` so that I can just say `Task` as the method return type instead of the fully qualified name.

However, now that I have imported said Nuget package, I get errors that `Task is a namespace but is used like a type.` This is because it is conflicting with the default system `Task` type namespace.

How can I resolve this in such a way that I don't have to fully qualify my usage of `Task`. Basically, I want to use by default `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` whenever I say `Task` and use `SomeAlias.Task` whenever I want something from the other task namespace.

Essentially, what I am looking for is a way to override the namespace that the nuget uses from my project. Changing the nuget itself is not an option.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Please read the question more closely. This does not solve the problem. The issue is caused by the fact that `MyCompany.Task` is a namespace (no using statement even involved yet) and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is a type. So I can't use the system Task type because C# thinks I'm trying to use something from the `MyCompany.Task` namespace.

Comment: `MyCompany.Task is a namespace (no using statement even involved yet)`, then add it. That will negate the conflict.

Comment: I've changed the title of your question.  Hopefully that will alleviate some of the confusion.

Comment: Good call @robert

Comment: @RyanWilson I tried that - it does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Bassinator One option I can think of then, convert the nuget package to a `dll`, then use dotnet peek or some other decompiler to change the namespace of the `dll`, then use it in your project.

Comment: @RyanWilson: Or just modify the original source from Github.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, if that is an option.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not.

Comment: Really what I'd like to do is remove `MyCompany.Task` from the list of namespaces that .NET can "see" when I write code, unless I specifically ask for the other namespace.

Comment: Well, what I'd _actually_ like to do is strangle the developer who thought it was a good idea to build a library with the same name as a super common .NET type, but that was 5 years ago and HR probably wouldn't like it.

Comment: @Bassinator Sounds like you work with a team of devs. What are other devs doing in their projects which utilizes this nuget package? I would hope that there is some kind of standard in place for your dev team to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the other projects which use this particular package have a totally different namespace and so don't have this issue.

Comment: @Bassinator So the other projects don't use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`? What does the project `namespace` have to do with it? Unless I am completely misreading, your problem is with the `namespace` of the `nuget` package and the use of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, not the `namespace` of your current working project.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, but you will need to use an alias for `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`

```
using SystemTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
```

Alternatively you can add an alias, to do this click the nuget in the references under solution explorer and open Properties, here you can set an Alias, for example myNuget. Then in any classes that need it add the below

```
extern alias myNuget;
using myNuget::MyCompany.Task;
```

Heres the documentation on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326678/how-to-override-a-namespace-from-a-nuget-in-c-sharp/65326749?noredirect=1#comment115491051_65326678

Comment: This is my fallback plan but I don't want to have to refactor my entire project to use this aliased type. I want to use the system type without fully qualifying it or aliasing it.

Comment: What I mean is that .NET for instance has a namespace resolution scope. So when I start typing something, it looks through all of it's namespaces to see if anything matches. What I want to do is remove `MyCompany.Task` from the list of namespaces that .NET looks through.

Comment: @Bassinator This is the only way I know of unfortunately unless you were to create a second project and a wrapper so you don't need to reference MyCompany.Task's nuget directly but that just sounds like more work than its worth.

Comment: @Bassinator I actually found a solution, extern alias, ive updated my answer, never even knew it existed